# Passing a Unicode path to Directory.Delete

Tags: .net, vb.net

We have a.NET application written in VB.NET targeting 4.7.2. The general idea of what this app does is downloads zip files, unzips them, does some transformation on some files, builds a new zip, uploads that, then cleans up the files from it's local storage. Some of these zips contains files that when extracted have a file path length greater than Windows max file path length.

Up until a couple of months ago this was all working fine with no issue but out of the blue started experiencing exceptions due to the file path length. We reprocessed a zip that had processed fine a few days before and it encountered the same issue. There were no changes on the server side that we could determine and the registry key to allow paths longer than the limit was set.

We ultimately took 2 actions, first having the team generating that zip review what was included and they were able to exclude the files that had the long paths. The other was in our application we began to prepend `\\?\` onto the file paths so they would be treated as Unicode paths.

However we have now encountered another zip with an issue, what we have found is if we try to pass a path beginning with `\\?\` to some APIs, in this case Directory.Delete which we use to recursively delete the unzipped files, it throws an exception due to illegal characters in the path. If we remove the `\\?\` from the path it throws an exception that it can't find part of the path and here again seems to be due to long file paths.

Does Directory.Delete not support Unicode paths?

Comment: Does you app have a Manifest that includes `<longPathAware ...>true</longPathAware >` in the `<windowsSettings>` branch? Associated with the Local Computer Policy that enables long paths.

Comment: Also what's the value of registry key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\ Control\FileSystem -> LongPathsEnabled`

Comment: The registry key is set to enable long paths, that was the first thing that we checked.

Comment: @Jimi It does not, I tried looking into that but couldn't get it to work are there any information you could provide on how to properly add the manifest

Comment: Since you have a .Net Fx 4.7.2 Project, you should already have the app.maifest. In Solution Explorer, click the `Show All Files` Button, then expand `My Project`. If `app.manifest` is already there, find the `<windowsSettings>` group (it should contain the `<dpiAware>` setting), uncomment it and add `<longPathAware xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2016/WindowsSettings">true</longPathAware>` if it's missing -- If the Manifest is not there, select `Project -> Add -> New Item...` and add a new Manifest file to the app. -- .Net 5+ apps already have this setting.

Comment: After that, start `gpedit.msc`, go to `Computer Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> All Settings` and check that `Enable Win32 long paths` is enabled. You'll see that the related Help box states: *Enabling Win32 long paths will allow **manifested** win32 applications and Windows Store applications to access paths beyond the normal 260 character limit*: the key is **`manifested`** -- The path length limit for your app should now be `32,760` characters.